# Ubuntu Server refusing to install without PAE/NX on in a VM

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-server

When I tried to start up a VM with the LiveServer ISO, it gave an error for a bug where it said that the CPU was "stuck". The error was fixed when I enabled the option for PAE/NX. Why would this be, if Ubuntu Server (by my knowledge) is 64-bit. Did I just have a corrupt ISO?